# How to invoke a templated static class method having tuple input in a constexpr way

Tags: c++, c++20, constexpr

How can a `static constexpr class::method (int i1, int i2, int i3)` be invoked, having input data available as `tuple<int, int, int>` in a constexpr way.

The default approach is using [std::apply](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/apply) to apply each tuple element as argument to a function.

A minimal example to visualize, what I try to achieve looks like:

```
struct a {
    template <typename T>
    static constexpr void test(int i1, int i2, int i3) {
        // ...
    }
};

struct b : a {};
struct c {};

template <typename T>
struct test_functor {
    constexpr test_functor_t() {} // just for testing to express constexpr desire
    constexpr void operator()(auto... args) {
        T::test<c>(args...);
    }
};

constexpr std::tuple<int, int, int> tupl{ 1,2,3 };
constexpr test_functor<b> f;
std::apply(f, tupl);
```

this works at runtime, but fails to compile `constexpr`. How can this be implemented?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: `std::apply` is `constexpr`. If the function you want to call is constexpr, what's the issue?

Comment: @NicolBolas the missing ```const``` declaration of ```operator()``` was the issue as ildjarn pointed out in 2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Working `test_functor`:

```
template <typename T>
struct test_functor {
    constexpr void operator()(auto... args) const {
        T::template test<c>(args...);
    }
};
```

The problems:

1. Your constructor was misnamed, and ultimately unnecessary – without a constructor your type is an aggregate and can be `constexpr`-constructed just fine.
2. Your `operator()` was not `const` – the primary problem, as you can't invoke a non-`const` member on a `constexpr` object.
3. Missing `template` keyword when invoking `T::test` – see [this FAQ answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/613132/636019) for a good explanation of dependent names.

<kbd>[**Online Demo**](https://godbolt.org/z/h8oPfbaG3)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the missing ```template``` keyword too. To improve 3. further, it should be ```T::template test<c>(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);```.

Comment: @Chris : Indeed, but only if you also change `args` into a pack of forwarding references; otherwise that `std::forward` is really a misleading/confusing `std::move`. ;-]